# Unanswered questions with answers?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, unanswered-questions

Why is it that many of the questions that appear when a user clicks "Unanswered" from the main page have answers?

What is the unanswered catagory? Is it questions without an *accepted* answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions that have no (net) up-voted answers are considered unanswered (unless an answer has been accepted without up-votes).

I know I've seen a better explanation than 
[this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4147/162102), but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18870/166155